# Facebook Like and Google+1 buttons on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like, google-plus

I have just added Facebook Like and Google+1 buttons to my website and both work fine on desktop machines.  However, on mobiles I have issues with both of them.  The Facebook Like button simply disappears when clicked on, whereas the Google button redirects to the Gmail login fine, but when logging in I just get a never ending loading screen.

Here is my relevant code :

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="myurl" data-text="Check out this site">Tweet</a>
              <br />
                <g:plusone size="medium" href="myurl"></g:plusone>
                <script>!function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>
           <br />
              <div style="padding-bottom:10px;" class="fb-like" data-href="myurl" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="false"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {lang: 'en-US'}
</script>
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ +1 button supports mobile web browsers, but only the +1ing action from it, not the additional sharing action. I had no problem signing in, seeing the loading screen, which went away and I was taken back to your site where I clicked +1. You should now see a count of 2. I used Chrome on Android. I did run into the loading problem on Chrome on iOS. However where that occurs, I don't think is a problem with your code, which looks fine. I believe its a problem on Google's side.

Comment: Thanks for testing the Google+1, I was only able to test on Windows Phone.  Did you get the issue I had with Facebook Like on Android or iOS?